# How to check if an iterator is an output_iterator in c++?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++-concepts

```
template<typename Iterator>
void put_value(Iterator pos, int n)
{
    static_assert(IsOutputIterator<Iterator>); 
    //
    // How to implement IsOutputIterator?
    //

    *pos = n;
}
```

`std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category` doesn't help. For example: `vector<int>::iterator` is obvious an `output_iterator`, but `std::iterator_traits<vector<int>::iterator>::iterator_category` will returns `random_access_iterator`, which might not be an `output_iterator`, say a `const_iterator`.

**Is there any viable way to check if an iterator is an output_iterator in c++?**

Comment: Any iterator other than from input iterator category is an output iterator.

Comment: A random access iterator meets all the requirements of an output iterator.

Comment: No, output iterator is may not allow to read. You can only write to it.

Comment: Fulfill all the requirements listed on the [Output Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) page.

Comment: @Eugene, is a const_iterator an output_iterator?

Comment: A `const_iterator` can be any kind of an iterator. But I can't see a `const_iterator` being a "pure" output iterator. A `const_iterator` can certainly be a forward, bidirectional, or a random access iterator, which all meet requirements for an output iterator.

Answer (score 4):

My first response is to ask "Output iterator for what?" C++ output iterators don't specify a value type, because the same iterator may be able to output multiple value types. The only way to determine if you can write a given expression `E` through a given iterator `o` is to see if `*o = std::declval<decltype((E))>()` is a valid expression.

In C++14, [I'd define a trait to do so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02e5a72d8502b414):

```
template <class...> using void_t = void;

template <class, class, class = void>
constexpr bool is_output_iterator = false;

template <class I, class E>
constexpr bool is_output_iterator<I, E, void_t<
    typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category,
    decltype(*std::declval<I>() = std::declval<E>())>> = true;
```

In C++ with concepts - which I assume you are interested in since you tagged this question with [c++-concepts](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts) - I would grab the [sample Ranges TS implementation from github](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2) and use its `OutputIterator<I, E>()` concept instead.